# cannot access server when i change inbound rules in security group

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, security-groups

I have installed mark logic server on public subnet, now the mark logic ui opens at http://publicip:8001 when the source of the security group is 0.0.0/0

Now i am trying to restrict the traffic and when i change the security group inbound rules to

```
type           protocol          port range                 source
all            all               all                 206.XXX.XXX.0/16(our proxy server ip)
```

i can ssh into instance but not connect to instance from web browser when i try to access ui using http://publicip:8001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try making your rules more specific - ie one for SSH, one for HTTP, one for HTTPS, with source 0.0.0.0/0. Then try changing the rules on a per rule basis, ideally making small gradual changes not a large jump to your target configuration.

You might also double check the outgoing IP address of the proxy in your web server logs, to make sure you've got it right.

It's not an answer, but I doubt anyone can give you an outright answer based on the information you've given.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was web sense that was blocking the request, so disabling it on my local machine helped, but as a permanent fix we are trying web sense url filtering with aws endpoints.